# NodeJS - Подскажите плагин для парсинга аргументов команды

Tags: node.js

Мне не нужен прасер аргументов командной строки. Мне нужно что-то наподобии того что парсится в движке source...

```
/setnick 10 "простой ник с пробелами.."
```

Как уже надеюсь догадались, в контре можно было ставить значения с пробелами с помощью кавычек.

Comment: и какой результат ожидается для приведенной строки?

Comment: [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)?

Comment: @Grundy Массив из 3 аргументов ['/setnick','10','простой ник с пробелами..']

Comment: @Yaant Думал что он для парсинга комманд лайн, но прочитав внимательнее увидел функцию command, спасибо.